# Can't get STM32 DAC to output anything

Tags: stm32, dac, stm32f10x

I'm trying to make a generic STM32F103 board output a sawtooth wave on DAC channel 1 but I'm getting nothing. The code is very straightforward and I've endlessly studied the datasheet, Google, various examples and tutorials. I just can't see what I'm missing here.

The IRQ function is being called at about 44.1KHz, and PORTA:0 is toggling correctly, but PORTA:4 is just 0 volts.

Can anyone see a mistake in this?

Reference manual is [here](http://www2.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf)

Datasheet is [here](http://www2.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/33/d4/6f/1d/df/0b/4c/6d/CD00161566.pdf/files/CD00161566.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00161566.pdf)

```
#include "misc.h"

extern "C" void TIM2_IRQHandler()
{
    static int i, j;

    // clear timer2 irq status
    TIM2->SR = (uint16_t)~TIM_IT_Update;

    // heartbeat toggle PORTA:0 every 256th tick
    (&GPIOA->BSRR)[(++i >> 8) & 1] = 0x1;

    // set new DAC data every tick
    DAC_SetChannel1Data(DAC_Align_12b_R, ++j & 0xfff);
}

int main()
{
    // switch on some peripheral clocks
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);   // PORTA
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);    // TIMER2
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_DAC, ENABLE);     // DAC

    // set PORTA:0 to output
    GPIO_InitTypeDef a0;
    a0.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
    a0.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    a0.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &a0);

    // set PORTA:4 to analog input (manual says to do this when using DAC Channel 1)
    GPIO_InitTypeDef a4;
    a4.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_4;
    a4.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AIN;
    a0.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &a4);

    // setup DAC channel 1
    DAC_InitTypeDef dacInit;
    dacInit.DAC_Trigger = DAC_Trigger_None;                             // set instantly
    dacInit.DAC_WaveGeneration = DAC_WaveGeneration_None;               // raw data
    dacInit.DAC_OutputBuffer = DAC_OutputBuffer_Enable;                 // enable filter
    dacInit.DAC_LFSRUnmask_TriangleAmplitude = DAC_LFSRUnmask_Bits8_0;  // filter level
    DAC_Init(DAC_Channel_1, &dacInit);
    DAC_Cmd(DAC_Channel_1, ENABLE);

    // enable TIMER2 IRQs
    NVIC_InitTypeDef nvicInit;
    nvicInit.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM2_IRQn;
    nvicInit.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;
    nvicInit.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
    nvicInit.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    NVIC_Init(&nvicInit);

    // setup timer2 @ approx 44.1KHz
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef timerInit;
    timerInit.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;     // set scale/period etc
    timerInit.TIM_Prescaler = 0;
    timerInit.TIM_Period = 36000000 / 44100 - 1;
    timerInit.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    timerInit.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &timerInit);

    TIM_ITConfig(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);          // switch on TIMER2 update IRQs

    TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);                              // start TIMER2

    while(1)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Link to the datasheet for your exact model, please

Comment: aaand it looks like it doesn't have a DAC on it. Blast, I could have sworn it did.

Comment: That's a bummer...

Comment: Hehe, was too busy reading the datasheet and answering, but apparently you figured it out anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. Your exact MCU model lacks the DAC subsystem. This is an error that is easy to make, because it is not always obvious. The manufacturers likes to brag about the features.

A DAC is less common than an ADC on microcontrollers. If you don't have an explicit DAC, you can often use a PWM channel as a DAC. Some microcontrollers have a high-speed PWM just for this purpose.